# Craftcms commerce product not showing

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Hi I know my way around CraftCMS and twig a little bit but totally new to the CraftCMS Commerce plugin. I have installed the Commerce plugin and I have added the default templates to get me started. There are a number of example products in a "Clothing" category which I assume the Commerce plugin added during installation.

When I click the "View" button from the edit page of one of those products I expect to see that product in the front end of the website using the example _product.twig template but instead just get the "New Website!" example news item. I don't know how to fix this. I deleted the news item to see what the product would link to instead but all I get now is the Home page.

I can see the product if I click "Preview" in the product editor and see it in split screen.

The URL seems to be correct such as: mywebsite.com/shop/products/ant-001

Can anyone tell me what schoolboy error I'm making?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I selected all in _product.twig and cut and then refreshed the page. Got a blank screen. I then pasted back in and it fixed the page. This was after emptying browser cache twice and trying different browsers that I hadn't previously used on the site. Odd but that fixed it. I was going to delete this post but decided to leave it in case anyone else has this problem. This was developing the site locally, using MAMP and gulp and Tailwindcss.